# Special characters in python

Tags: python, special-characters

I have a file with a lot of entries about Nobel prizes. I than convert that file into a list like this:

```
file = open(path, 'r')
file.readline()
content = []
for line in file:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    content.append(line.split(';'))

content = check(content, 'röntgen')
```

After that I have a function that takes that list and a other argument and checks if the list contains that argument. However if the argument takes a special character like the Ö it doen’t work because when the file is read python saves it like: Ã¶

```
def check(content, attr):
reducedList = []
for i in range(len(content)):
    curr = content[i][4]
    if curr.find(attr) != -1:
        reducedList.append(content[i])
return reducedList
```

with:

```
curr = 'voor hun verdiensten op het gebied van de analyse van de kristalstructuur door middel van rÃ¶ntgenstraling'
attr = 'röntgen'
```

I have tried converting it with utf-8 but that doesn’t seem to help. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: try the iso-8859-1 encoding

Comment: Are both your python file and your text file encoded using UTF-8 ?

Comment: the python file is encoded with # -\*- coding: utf-8 -\*-
and the text file is encode in utf-8

Comment: Check your encoding and open your file specifying the correct one, eg file=open(path, encoding='utf-8', 'r').

Comment: yes it worked with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8'), thank you!

Comment: It worked - but the rest of yoru program tries to use byte-strigns as text  - that is justa time bomb. Please, read the article I indicate bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to replace `open(path,’r’,)` with `open(path,’r’,encodeing=’utf-8’)`
If you add de encodeing parameter python will make sure de file is read in utf-8 so when you compare the strings they are truly the same.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using Python 2, likely on Windows, and your file is encoded in utf-8, not latin-1.

The best thng you do, instead of trying to randomly fix it (including with the first comments to your question: they are all random suggestions,), is to understand what is going on. So, stop what you are trying to do.

Read this:
https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Then, switch to Python3 if you can - that should handle most issues automatically.

If you can't you have to proper deal with the text decoding and re-encoding manually - the concepts are on the link above. Assume your input files are in utf-8

Comment: I'm using the python 3.5 compiler. and I do understand completely what is going on. I restored here not because I didn't know what was going on I didn't know what I was supposed to do with the problem.